# Can I define a group of tables for later handling?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I have created a set of tables, namely TABLE_1, TABLE_2, TABLE_3, &c. I created a set of roles as well, namely ROLE_1.

I want to know if there is a way to grant the same role to all those tables in a single sentence. I'm not sure if there is a type of grouping for tables, let's say TABLE_GROUP_1.

```
     GRANT SELECT ON TABLE_GROUP_1 TO ROLE_1;
```

Today I would need to do:

```
     GRANT SELECT ON TABLE_1 TO ROLE_1;
     GRANT SELECT ON TABLE_2 TO ROLE_1;
     GRANT SELECT ON TABLE_3 TO ROLE_1;
```

Please let me know if there is some kind of object that works like that. It would be useful for either Oracle or MySQL (I can find equivalences later).

Comment: No, actually it was not what I was looking for.

Comment: Well, it resolves in the sense of "it is not possible" & in the workaround part of it. I think I was looking for a fancy solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cant it doesnt work like in one line